# Need to read specific lines of text file that doesn't have a great format into data frame (preferably multiple data frames)?

Tags: r

I'm completely new to R and I'm not sure the best way to deal with this file so I'm really hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction. I've searched for other solutions and tried using grepl but can't seem to figure out the best way to only read some of the data. The file I'm trying to read in looks something like the text below:

```
##BLOCKS= 8          
Plate:  Plate01 1.3 PlateFormat Endpoint    Absorbance  Raw FALSE   1               1   630 1   12  96  1   8   None    
Temperature(°C) 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      
0.00            0.042   0.067   0.292   0.206   0.071   0.067   0.04    0.063   0.059   0.04    0.066   0.04        
                0.043   0.172   0.179   0.199   0.073   0.067   0.04    0.062   0.058   0.039   0.066   0.039       
                 0.04   0.066   0.29    0.185   0.072   0.067   0.04    0.062   0.058   0.039   0.065   0.039       
                0.039   0.068   0.291   0.189   0.075   0.069   0.04    0.064   0.058   0.041   0.064   0.039       
                0.042   0.063   0.271   0.191   0.07    0.068   0.04    0.065   0.058   0.041   0.066   0.04        
                0.041   0.067   0.342   0.199   0.069   0.066   0.041   0.065   0.057   0.04    0.065   0.042       
                0.044   0.064   0.295   0.198   0.069   0.067   0.039   0.064   0.057   0.04    0.067   0.041       
                0.041   0.067   0.29    0.211   0.066   0.067   0.043   0.056   0.058   0.042   0.067   0.042       

~End
Plate:  Plate#1 1.3 PlateFormat Endpoint    Absorbance  Raw FALSE   1                       1   630 1   12  96  1   8   None    
Temperature(°C) 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      
0.00            0.042   0.072   0.257   0.165   0.074   0.07    0.04    0.067   0.055   0.04    0.07    0.04        
                0.042   0.164   0.136   0.195   0.075   0.07    0.041   0.066   0.055   0.04    0.069   0.04        
                0.041   0.07    0.344   0.198   0.074   0.069   0.041   0.065   0.055   0.04    0.068   0.04        
                0.04    0.069   0.307   0.199   0.075   0.072   0.041   0.067   0.055   0.043   0.068   0.041       
                0.043   0.068   0.296   0.214   0.072   0.071   0.042   0.067   0.055   0.041   0.068   0.041       
                0.041   0.071   0.452   0.241   0.072   0.069   0.042   0.067   0.054   0.041   0.068   0.043       
                0.044   0.068   0.299   0.182   0.071   0.071   0.042   0.067   0.054   0.041   0.069   0.041       
                0.042   0.071   0.333   0.13    0.068   0.07    0.042   0.058   0.054   0.042   0.07    0.041       

~End
```

I only want the columns/rows numbered 1-12 (next to Temperature) and the data under them. I'm new to R but do have some programming experience so I don't necessarily need someone to tell me exactly how to do this but if anyone could at least point me in the right direction of whatever functions I should be looking at I'd really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Get the data into R session with `readLines`

```
Lines <- readLines(textConnection("##BLOCKS= 8          
Plate:  Plate01 1.3 PlateFormat Endpoint    Absorbance  Raw FALSE   1               1   630 1   12  96  1   8   None    
Temperature(°C) 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      
0.00            0.042   0.067   0.292   0.206   0.071   0.067   0.04    0.063   0.059   0.04    0.066   0.04        
                0.043   0.172   0.179   0.199   0.073   0.067   0.04    0.062   0.058   0.039   0.066   0.039       
                 0.04   0.066   0.29    0.185   0.072   0.067   0.04    0.062   0.058   0.039   0.065   0.039       
                0.039   0.068   0.291   0.189   0.075   0.069   0.04    0.064   0.058   0.041   0.064   0.039       
                0.042   0.063   0.271   0.191   0.07    0.068   0.04    0.065   0.058   0.041   0.066   0.04        
                0.041   0.067   0.342   0.199   0.069   0.066   0.041   0.065   0.057   0.04    0.065   0.042       
                0.044   0.064   0.295   0.198   0.069   0.067   0.039   0.064   0.057   0.04    0.067   0.041       
                0.041   0.067   0.29    0.211   0.066   0.067   0.043   0.056   0.058   0.042   0.067   0.042       

~End
Plate:  Plate#1 1.3 PlateFormat Endpoint    Absorbance  Raw FALSE   1                       1   630 1   12  96  1   8   None    
Temperature(°C) 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      
0.00            0.042   0.072   0.257   0.165   0.074   0.07    0.04    0.067   0.055   0.04    0.07    0.04        
                0.042   0.164   0.136   0.195   0.075   0.07    0.041   0.066   0.055   0.04    0.069   0.04        
                0.041   0.07    0.344   0.198   0.074   0.069   0.041   0.065   0.055   0.04    0.068   0.04        
                0.04    0.069   0.307   0.199   0.075   0.072   0.041   0.067   0.055   0.043   0.068   0.041       
                0.043   0.068   0.296   0.214   0.072   0.071   0.042   0.067   0.055   0.041   0.068   0.041       
                0.041   0.071   0.452   0.241   0.072   0.069   0.042   0.067   0.054   0.041   0.068   0.043       
                0.044   0.068   0.299   0.182   0.071   0.071   0.042   0.067   0.054   0.041   0.069   0.041       
                0.042   0.071   0.333   0.13    0.068   0.07    0.042   0.058   0.054   0.042   0.07    0.041       

~End"))
```

Steps 2 & 3: Build a conditional to include good data lines, and grouping

```
?strsplit 
# Couldn't remember name of `substr`, figured the ?strsplit  page would show link

start <- substr(Lines, 1,1)  # 1st char was sufficient to build a rule
table(start)
#--- result ----
start
       #  ~  0  P  T      # the 14 is the count of " " (just spaces)
 2 14  1  2  2  2  2 
#end table
goodL <- Lines[start %in% c(" ","T","0")  ]
goodL  # Look at result

group <- cumsum(substr(goodL , 1,4)=="Temp")  #build grouping
group   # check the grouping variable
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Step 4:  Process the groups with `lapply(split(goodL, group), function(x) ...`

```
dfrms <- lapply(split(goodL, group), 
             function(x) read.table(text=substr(x,16,  # stuff to right of 16th char
                                                     100),header=TRUE))
str(dfrms)  # check result,,, not correct, need 12th entry
List of 2
 $ 1:'data.frame':  8 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ X1 : num [1:8] 0.042 0.043 0.04 0.039 0.042 0.041 0.044 0.041
  ..$ X2 : num [1:8] 0.067 0.172 0.066 0.068 0.063 0.067 0.064 0.067
 #   -----snipped output

 dfrms <- lapply(split(goodL, group),   # will be a list of dataframes
            function(x) read.table(text =substr(x, 16, 120), header=TRUE))
 str(dfrms)   # Looks good
List of 2
 $ 1:'data.frame':  8 obs. of  12 variables:
  ..$ X1 : num [1:8] 0.042 0.043 0.04 0.039 0.042 0.041 0.044 0.041
  ..$ X2 : num [1:8] 0.067 0.172 0.066 0.068 0.063 0.067 0.064 0.067
  ..$ X3 : num [1:8] 0.292 0.179 0.29 0.291 0.271 0.342 0.295 0.29
 #--- snippped output
```

I'd like to give credit to @G.Grothendieck for this strategy. Doing a search on "user:516548 readLines" will pull up many other elegant examples of a similar approach.

Comment: Thank you! I won't be able to try this out for another couple hours but I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Ok so when "group" prints it's printing "integer(0)". It's a tab delimited text file which I didn't mention so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Not sure why group would be an empty vector. Maybe you gave the wrong type of connection argument to readLines?  If that's a TSV file, you might need to use `sep="\t"` in the `read.table` arguments (once you figure out why group is empty.)

Comment: Ok I think the problem is when I use readLines it's including all the tabs so when I use "start %in% c(" ","T","0")" it's not finding anything. Is there an easy way to remove the tabs after using readLines or a way to load the file with the tabs removed then use readLines?

Comment: If the result of `readLines` is `res` then I think you can do: `res2 <- gsub("\\\t" , " ", res)`   convert tabs to single spaces. The choice of  number of extra backslashes for regex patterns is one of those "mysteries" that attend learning R. Perhaps not coincidentally, I also credit @G.Grothendieck with teaching me most of what I know of R regular expressions.